# Find the properties that have the highest cash flow sum that's their price sum doesn't exceed the budget

Tags: javascript, php, recursion

Challenge: Find the properties that have the highest cash flow sum that's their price sum doesn't exceed the budget.

I need help to find the best possible combination of "X" properties that doesn't exceed my budget of $300,000 (or "X"), and provides the highest return on cash flow. There are over 800,000 properties in the database, so I am trying to come up with an algorithm that is efficient too.

Here are some data to help get started...

```
function findBestCombination( budget ) {

    var budget = budget;
    var cashflow = 0;
    var bestCombination = [];
    var properties = [  {price: 51000, cashflow: 1200},
                        {price: 74900, cashflow: 7866},
                        {price: 139000, cashflow: 6426},
                        {price: 129900, cashflow: 7587},
                        {price: 115000, cashflow: 7681},
                        {price: 137900, cashflow: 10867},
                        {price: 109900, cashflow: 9158},
                        {price: 169900, cashflow: 10066},
                        {price: 134900, cashflow: 7925},
                        {price: 219900, cashflow: 12106},
                        {price: 102500, cashflow: 7144},
                        {price: 109900, cashflow: 8648},
                        {price: 124900, cashflow: 8429},
                        {price: 63200, cashflow: 8754},
                        {price: 71000, cashflow: 5807},
                        {price: 116600, cashflow: 8088},
                        {price: 37500, cashflow: 4524},
                        {price: 56000, cashflow: 2951},
                        {price: 63600, cashflow: 8062},
                        {price: 97600, cashflow: 9171},
                        {price: 83740, cashflow: 8102},
                        {price: 66800, cashflow: 4815},
                        {price: 138900, cashflow: 3935},
                        {price: 65100, cashflow: 4806},
                        {price: 34600, cashflow: 4614},
                        {price: 101300, cashflow: 7022},
                        {price: 43600, cashflow: 6309},
                        {price: 175000, cashflow: 9102},
                        {price: 89000, cashflow: 9276},
                        {price: 46600, cashflow: 3595},
                     ]
    ??.............??

}

findBestCombination(300000);
```

Thank you! (I'm using PHP and Javascript)

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: This sounds like the *"Knapsack Problem"* see: https://gist.github.com/danwoods/7496329 and/or https://ljvmiranda.wordpress.com/2016/02/25/how-to-solve-knapsack-problem-in-javascript/

Comment: No it's not homework

Comment: @JonSG Thank you! I found a solution with that!